# Integrability of $e^{iax}$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory

I have the following function $f_\epsilon(x)=e^{iax-\epsilon|x|}$

I need to show that $f_\epsilon$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and that $e^{iax}$ defines a tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.

In both cases I need to study the integrablity of $e^{iax}$, which as I far as I know isn't integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Comment: But don't you really need to study integrability of $|e^{iax-\epsilon|x|}|$, which is $e^{-\epsilon|x|}$? And isn't that obvious?

Comment: @MPW what's confusing me is that $|.|$ is supposed to be the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$ and not the modulus on $\mathbb{C}$ no ? If it is indeed the case, do I proceed like this: \begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\epsilon|x|}&=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\epsilon x}\\
&=2[e^{-\epsilon x}/\epsilon]_{0}^\infty <\infty
\end{align}